# How to create directed graph with nodes having multiple data?

Tags: c++, graph, treenode, vertex, directed-graph

I want to create a graph with nodes and edges, where each node will contain `n` number of values. We would be given with the `n` values of the starting node, from which we need to generate other nodes where each value in each node would be of the form either:

```
t_n=t_(n-1)+2
```

or

```
t_n=t_(n-1)-1
```

When such a node is generated, it should create an edge from the old node to the new node.

I know this might be very trivial job, but I have very limited programming knowledge. I have been suggested to use classes in C++ or structure to represent the nodes. Please help me in creating the graph with nodes that would have multiple values and further the next nodes would be generated from the parent node following the above rule. Some C++ code would be very helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

[here you have some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225740/how-to-create-graph-from-vertex) but I don't really fully understand your task.

```
- graph with nodes and edges
- each node has n number of values
- we are given n values of the starting point
- need to generate other nodes where each value in each node would be either
    - t_n=t_(n-1)+2
    - t_n=t_(n-1)-1

- when such node is generated, it creates an edge from the old node to the new node.
```

this starting point: do we have to generate a graph from it? what is with the creation of the edge from the old node and the new node? is old node here the starting point?

does n number of values means to where the point is connected to (as a chain of the other edges to which this edge is connected to)? example we are provided a node with a chain of numbers (6, 4, 5) where this means we need to generate extra edges which would be connected x times (first one linked to our starting point would be linked to 6 edges, one of them being the starting point)

will edit my answer when I have more information. could you please draw an example in paint and upload it online and provide the link? it would be easier to imagine.

Comment: just noticed the "directed graph". that slipped my eyes earlier. that means one edge can point to multiple other edges, where it is not necessary for them to point back to this edge. interesting. (still I need your task more clearly explained)