# How to create graph from vertex?

Tags: c++, opengl, graph

I have a list of connected vertexes.

My question is how to create and store a graph that represents this list?.

For example for

```
5
2 4 5
1 3 4
2 4 5
1 2 3 5
1 3 4
```

1 is connected to 2, 4, 5

2 -> 1, 3, 4

and so on..

Here is 2 (the same) representations.
[image]

And my second question is how to get all representations of that graph (in this image i showed 2, that are the same)
For one list of vertexes exists only one graphical represantation? if more, how to get all of that?

in image they are the same, differente drawings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
5 means how many lines
1 > 2, 4, 5
2 > 1, 3, 4
3 > 2, 4, 5
4 > 1, 2, 3, 5
5 > 1, 3, 4
```

(I am silly so I needed to type this in notepad).

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Cl_Graph;
class Cl_Chain;

class Cl_Vertex
{
friend Cl_Graph;
private:
    Cl_Chain* mp_linkedTo;
    Cl_Vertex();
    void f_addLink(Cl_Vertex* in_link);
};

Cl_Vertex::Cl_Vertex()
{
    mp_linkedTo= NULL;
}

class Cl_Graph
{
private:
    int m_size;
    Cl_Vertex* pm_vertexTable;
public:
    Cl_Graph(int in_size);
    void f_addLink(int in_index, int in_linkWith);
};

Cl_Graph::Cl_Graph(int in_size)
{
    pm_vertexTable= new Cl_Vertex[m_size= in_size];
}

void Cl_Graph::f_addLink(int in_index, int in_linkWith)
{
    if (in_index< m_size && in_linkWith< m_size)
    {
        pm_vertexTable[in_index].f_addLink(pm_vertexTable[in_linkWith]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Cl_Graph graph(5);
    graph.f_addLink(1, 2);
    graph.f_addLink(1, 4);
    graph.f_addLink(1, 5);
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

You can start with something like this. You can even type a function that would get a chain of vertexes as argument to add to graph, and instead of the array it can have a chain of link chains :p good luck!

Comment: About the second question, each point of where vertexes are connected can be anywhere in the 3D space so of course more pictures can be drawn. Each corner should always have the same lines, unless two corners share the exact same location.

Comment: Thanks. It's definitely that i was searching for. :)